# Dropdown Filter by product or items

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I just made a simple front-end page using HTML and CSS. this page has two kinds of products which are a camera and dvr. i want to filter the camera when I select the camera from the dropdown and the same with the dvr. but I don't know how to do this. I tried to use list.js but didn't work.

this is my HTML code for the page.
Filter code part

```
<nav class="product-filter">
        <h1>Security Products</h1>
        <div class="sort">
          <div class="collection-sort">
            <label>Filter by:</label>
            <select id="list" onchange="getSelectedValue()">
              <option selected="selected">Select a product</option>
              <option value="camera">Camera</option>
              <option value="dvr">DVR</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Product card code(1st one is the camera. 2nd one is DVR)

```
      <section class="products">
        <div class="product-card camera">
            <div class="product-image">
                <img src="assets/images/services/hikvision/1.jpg">
                <span id="item-description">CAMERA</span>
            </div>
            <div class="product-info">
                <h5>Hikvision ColorVu Series</h5>
                <h6>$99.99</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="product-card dvr">
            <div class="product-image">
                <img src="assets/images/services/hikvision/2.jpg">
                <span id="item-description">DVR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="product-info">
                <h5>Hikvision Value Series</h5>
                <h6>$99.99</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>
```

Additionally, I have added to get the value from dropdown using JS. it only shows the value in the console.

```
<script>
        function getSelectedValue() {
            var selectValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
            console.log(selectValue);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Will there be multiple products i.e multiple `camera` or `DVR`?

Comment: yes maybe. but only like 3 or 4 maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother. you can try this. This will filter all the cards with `camera` class when the camera will be selected. Hope it will help. Thank you.

```js
function getSelectedValue() {
  const selectValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
  const acceptedValues = ['camera', 'dvr'];
  const productCards = document.querySelectorAll('.product-card');

  productCards.forEach(card => {
    if(acceptedValues.includes(selectValue)) {
      if(card.classList.contains(selectValue)) {
        card.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        card.style.display = 'none';
      }
    } else {
      card.style.display = 'block';
    }
  })
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.product-card {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="product-filter">
  <h1>Security Products</h1>
  <div class="sort">
    <div class="collection-sort">
      <label>Filter by:</label>
      <select id="list" onchange="getSelectedValue()">
        <option selected="selected">Select a product</option>
        <option value="camera">Camera</option>
        <option value="dvr">DVR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    
<section class="products">
  <div class="product-card camera">
    <div class="product-image">
      <h4 id="item-description">CAMERA</h4>
      <img src="https://www.borrowlenses.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/vlogging-gear-best-of-2019.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h5>Hikvision ColorVu Series</h5>
      <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card dvr">
    <div class="product-image">
        <h4 id="item-description">DVR</h4>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQn4SUVDMC9q4Pa2Bvf0GJDbEwdFnKeC6AzcQ&usqp=CAU">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
        <h5>Hikvision Value Series</h5>
        <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card camera">
    <div class="product-image">
      <h4 id="item-description">CAMERA</h4>
      <img src="https://www.borrowlenses.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/vlogging-gear-best-of-2019.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h5>Hikvision ColorVu Series</h5>
      <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card camera">
    <div class="product-image">
      <h4 id="item-description">CAMERA</h4>
      <img src="https://www.borrowlenses.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/vlogging-gear-best-of-2019.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h5>Hikvision ColorVu Series</h5>
      <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card dvr">
    <div class="product-image">
        <h4 id="item-description">DVR</h4>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQn4SUVDMC9q4Pa2Bvf0GJDbEwdFnKeC6AzcQ&usqp=CAU">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
        <h5>Hikvision Value Series</h5>
        <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card dvr">
    <div class="product-image">
        <h4 id="item-description">DVR</h4>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQn4SUVDMC9q4Pa2Bvf0GJDbEwdFnKeC6AzcQ&usqp=CAU">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
        <h5>Hikvision Value Series</h5>
        <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: hey brother ! this works. a very small thing, I also need to show all the items when I select "select a product". how can i do this?

Comment: Hello brother, I just made an edit. Now you will get what wanted. Please check out the solution again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can all `value="all"` in html for "Select a product" option and use the function to show and hide..

```
<option value="all" selected="selected">Select a product</option>
```

```js
function getSelectedValue() {
  const camera = document.querySelector(".camera");
  const dvr = document.querySelector(".dvr");
  const value = document.getElementById("list").value;
  const displayCamera = value === "camera" || value === "all" ? "block" : "none";
  const displayDvr = value === "dvr" || value === "all" ? "block" : "none";
  camera.style.display = displayCamera;
  dvr.style.display = displayDvr;
}
```

```html
<nav class="product-filter">
  <h1>Security Products</h1>
  <div class="sort">
    <div class="collection-sort">
      <label>Filter by:</label>
      <select id="list" onchange="getSelectedValue()">
        <option value="all" selected="selected">Select a product</option>
        <option value="camera">Camera</option>
        <option value="dvr">DVR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<section class="products">
  <div class="product-card camera">
    <div class="product-image">
      <img src="assets/images/services/hikvision/1.jpg">
      <span id="item-description">CAMERA</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h5>Hikvision ColorVu Series</h5>
      <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-card dvr">
    <div class="product-image">
      <img src="assets/images/services/hikvision/2.jpg">
      <span id="item-description">DVR</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h5>Hikvision Value Series</h5>
      <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cameraContainer = document.querySelector(".camera");
const dvrContainer = document.querySelector(".dvr");

function getSelectedValue() {
  var selectValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
  if (selectValue === "camera") {
    cameraContainer.style.display = "block";
    dvrContainer.style.display = "none";
  } else if (selectValue === "dvr") {
    cameraContainer.style.display = "none";
    dvrContainer.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    cameraContainer.style.display = "block";
    dvrContainer.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="product-filter">
  <h1>Security Products</h1>
  <div class="sort">
    <div class="collection-sort">
      <label>Filter by:</label>
      <select id="list" onchange="getSelectedValue()">
        <option selected="selected">Select a product</option>
        <option value="camera">Camera</option>
        <option value="dvr">DVR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<section class="products">
  <div class="product-card camera">
    <div class="product-image">
      <img src="assets/images/services/hikvision/1.jpg">
      <span id="item-description">CAMERA</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h5>Hikvision ColorVu Series</h5>
      <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-card dvr">
    <div class="product-image">
      <img src="assets/images/services/hikvision/2.jpg">
      <span id="item-description">DVR</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h5>Hikvision Value Series</h5>
      <h6>$99.99</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

or you can make a function and make it easy to understand and easy to debug

```
const cameraContainer = document.querySelector(".camera");
const dvrContainer = document.querySelector(".dvr");

function showCameraContainer(show) {
    const display = show ? "block" : "none";
    cameraContainer.style.display = display;
}

function showDVRContainer(show) {
    const display = show ? "block" : "none";
    dvrContainer.style.display = display;
}

function getSelectedValue() {
    var selectValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
    console.log(selectValue);
    if (selectValue === "camera") {
        showCameraContainer(true);
        showDVRContainer(false);
    } else if (selectValue === "dvr") {
        showCameraContainer(false);
        showDVRContainer(true);
    } else {
        showCameraContainer(true);
        showDVRContainer(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null. why is that?

Comment: Are you defining the `cameraContainer` and `dvrContainer` ?

Comment: yes. I pasted the code exactly like it is. there are 10 products currently.

Comment: can you make a copy of your code on codesandbox or jsfiddle. So that I can understand what's the problem